# Angular is waiting anoher request to start

Tags: angularjs, ajax

In my App I need to do a request to save some data (this request is little slow) but the user can do another request in same time, when he did this, angular was waiting for the first request (not assync). How Can I do two requests whithout waiting for other?

My slow service:

```
app.service('PedSaveService',["$http", "$q","BASEURL",
                       function ($http, $q,BASEURL) {
                           var self = this;

                           self.Save = function (pedidoData) {
                               var deferred = $q.defer();                
                               $http({method: 'POST',async: true, url: BASEURL.REST_SAVE, headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'}, data : pedidoData})
                                   .success(function (response, status, headers, config) {
                                       deferred.resolve(response, status, headers, config);
                                   })
                                   .error(function (response, status, headers, config) {
                                       deferred.reject(response, status, headers, config);
                                   });

                               return deferred.promise;
                           }
```

Comment: Why is your request not async?

Comment: Yes, I did. In $http async: true and in module I add $httpProvider.useApplyAsync(true);. But it doen't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.Save = function(pedidoData) {
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    async: true,
    url: BASEURL.REST_SAVE,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    },
    data: pedidoData
}).then(function(res) {
    return res;
}); }
```

Your code in service should be this.

Comment: I did this, but it doen't work. My http call: 
$http({method: 'POST',async: true, url:MY_URL, headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'}, data : pedidoData});

Comment: Make sure you are not making the second http request in .then of the first http request. Also you are not using any other promise library.

Comment: No, I didn't, I have one function that call a service (slow service) and I have another function in other code that call the second request.

Comment: You have used q promise library in your service due to which it will wait for the result of your http request in service before performing second http request. Just remove it and make a simple http request.

Comment: Didn't work =/, I did another test, when I call this service, if I try to load other page of my app in other tab on google chrome, this new page only load after the Save response.